# Navigation causes an out of memory exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am working on a windows phone app (really big one) that has at least 60 different pages, on some navigation i am getting a "out of memory error". This is usually happening on the last pages (on the navigation flow). I am using `NavigationService.navigate("MyURL");` to go move to the next page and `NavigationService.goback();` to navigate to a the page before, there is any better approach for this type of navigation?

If am not clear enough please tell me(English is not my first language)

Comment: When the "out of memory" error kicks in, how many pages do you have in the backstack? If you have more than 4 or 5 pages, you should probably rethink your navigation flow.

Comment: Usually 5 to 6 depending, the longest navigation possible in the app has 6 pages but that last one can be a picture, and that is one of the error triggres

Comment: Have you considered that the picture is the one causing the "Out of Memory" error? What is the size, dimensions and format of the picture?

Comment: The picture is around 250kb to 1mb jpg 600 x 480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for this problem after a few weeks I create a Navigation manager and start deleting the unwanted back stack with that y reduce the problem, after that did some edits to the Picture View Class instead of allowing the user to rotate de picture and all,  just present the picture, so far a haven’t see that error again